# C# Reading Process Memory

Tags: c#, memory

My Class that i used:
http://pastebin.com/GMq5eZ42

i call it whit this in my Main Application
But it still says the Index is out of arrayfield

```
        int memoryaddress = 0x5C;
        int bytesread;
        double memoryaddressvalue;
        byte[] memoryvalue;


        memoryvalue = ReadCoords.ReadMemoryAtAdress((IntPtr)memoryaddress, 4, out bytesread);


        memoryaddressvalue = BitConverter.ToDouble(memoryvalue, 0);
        Label1 = Convert.ToString(memoryaddressvalue);
```

Comment: did you try 0x005C or 0x00C5

Comment: Voting to close as there is not enough details in the question: please post *small complete sample inline* in the question (links to source are ok as additional details). Also please post exact error message/call stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read what is at address 0x5c in process Nksp.exe.

How did you come up with 0x5c? This is probably your problem.

The first page of a virtual address space in Windows is a guard page (that's how null pointer dereferences are trapped by the OS). 0x5c should fall in this page and hence make you no good.